# R for loop over all files in directory and in all subdirectories

Tags: r, list, loops, directory

I'm not sure how to create reproducible data using multiple directories, so I'm just going to explain the structure of my directory.

I have a parent folder called `Data`. Under `Data`, I have dozens of folders named `Sample1`, `Sample2`, `Sample3` and so on. Each of these folders have `txt` files that are formatted in the same way.

I currently have a loop that works over all files in `Sample1`, like below:

```
file_list <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Sample1/", pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
all_list <- vector("list", "length" = length(file_list)

for (i in seq_along(file_list)){
   filename <- file_list[[i]]

   ## I do more things here, but I'm abbreviating this part to make the question simpler
   df1 <- read.table(filename, sep = " ")
   df1$col1 <- df1$col2 + df1$col3

   all_list[[i]] <- df1
}

all_df <- do.call(rbind, all_list)
```

Now I'm trying to make this code work over all folders under `Data` (`Sample1`, `Sample2`, ....). I pulled out the folder paths using the  code below:

```
parent_folder <- "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data"
sub_folders <- list.dirs(parent_folder, recursive = TRUE) [-1]
```

I need to repeat the loop above for all of these `sub_folders`. I think the start of the loop would look like this:

```
for (j in seq_along(sub_folders)){
   all_file_list <- vector("list", length = length(sub_folders)
   file_list <- list.files(path = sub_folders[j], pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
   ...
}
```

Then I started to get a bit confused now because there seems to be so many lists. `file_list`, `all_list` and `all_df` from the code above (that worked in the `Sample1` folder) would all need to be saved as lists so that it can contain information from all the `sub_folders`? This also doesn't feel very efficient, but I'm not sure if there are ways to make this simpler. Can anyone give me any suggestions on what to try out?

Comment: Why couldn't you just have it get all the files recursively, `file_list <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/", pattern = "*.txt", recursive=TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [`dir_ls()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/dir_ls.html) function from the [fs package](https://fs.r-lib.org/index.html) to find all of the required files recursively, i.e.

```
library(fs)
file_list <- fs::dir_ls(path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data/Sample1/", recurse = TRUE, type = "file", glob = "*.txt")
```

Then pass that list of file paths/names to [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) to read them into a single dataframe, conduct your data manipulations 'once' on that large dataframe, then split the large dataframe into smaller dataframes (one per sample):

```
library(vroom)
data <- vroom::vroom(file_list, id = "sample")
data$col1 <- data$col2 + data$col3

# split the df into smaller dfs (one df per sample)
list_of_dfs <- split(data, data$sample)
list2env(list_of_dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I don't know if this will work for your intended purposes (maybe the 'large' dataframe will be too big for your system to handle), but I use a similar workflow in one of my projects and it's a lot faster than reading in and manipulating each 'sample' with a for loop.