# Read csv files in the order they appear in the wanted file

Tags: r, csv

I have 21 CSV files that I want to read starting from the first file, to the last, they are numbered and they have the same pattern. It is very important to keep them in this order when reading them. The names look something like this:

```
xGenes_tpm1.csv
xGenes_tpm2.csv
xGenes_tpm3.csv
xGenes_tpm4.csv
.
.
.
xGenes_tpm21.csv
```

They are not in the home directory, therefore I need to specify the path. I did it like this:

```
folder_path = '/Bigfolder/Genes/result_csvs/'
temp = list.files(path = folder_path , pattern="xGenes", full.names = F)
file_number = stringr::str_extract(temp, "[0-9]+") |> as.numeric()
correct_index_order = sapply(sort(file_number), \(x) which(file_number == x))
temp = temp[correct_index_order]
scores = lapply(file.path(folder_path, temp), read.csv)

scores = lapply(temp, read.csv)
final_Scores = Reduce(cbind, scores)
```

I get this error, in the line before the last:

```
> scores = lapply(temp, read.csv)
Error in file(file, "rt") : 
  (converted from warning) cannot open file 'xGenes_tpm1.csv': No such file or directory
```

The path I'm using is correct and the names are correct. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have two calls attempting to read the files `scores = lapply(file.path(folder_path, temp), read.csv)` and `scores = lapply(temp, read.csv)`.  I expect from your code the former works as it contains the full path and the latter fails as it does not. But as your code is not reproducible, we can only speculate.

Comment: This line `scores = lapply(file.path(folder_path, temp), read.csv)` reads each data set multiple times. In total I get a list of 441 data sets, when I have only 21... how can I provide more data for it to be reproducible? I will gladly provide it. @RitchieSacramento

Comment: Would [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949137/12957340) work for you? This method provides you with a single dataframe with an "id" column that lists the file of origin. You can then sort by "id" (or in your case, by `stringr::str_extract(id, "[0-9]+")` or however suits)